# Baby Rudin section 10.28 on Affine Chains: if $\Gamma=\sigma_1+\sigma_2 = 0$ ,then why $\int_{\Gamma}\omega=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, differential-forms

My question is this:

I don't understand if $\Gamma=\sigma_1+\sigma_2=0$ ,then why is it necessary for $\int_{\Gamma}$ $\omega$ to be equal to  $0$?

[image]

Comment: You typed wrongly. You should type `$a+b$`. not `$a$+$b$`. please type the important mathematical content with Mathjax. This helps users with slow connections, poor eyesight, or maybe imgur is blocked in their workplace. You can get started [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/80734), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

I think you there are two ways to think about this. One is that integration is some kind of a summation, and empty sum is usually by definition 0. The other is if we denote by $C_n(E)$ the $n$-chains in $E$ which are just formal sum of maps from the standard $n$-simplex to $E$, and denote by $\Omega_n(E)$ the differential $n$-forms on $E$, then you should think about integration as a bilinear map $\int:C_n(E)\times \Omega_n(E)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If you have $\Gamma=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\sigma_i\in C_n(E)$ and $\omega\in \Omega_n(E)$, then $\int (\Gamma,\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\int_{\sigma_i} \omega$. Now it is standard result in linear algebra that if $B$ is a bilinear form then $B(0,-)$ is the zero function.

Comment: Your explanation is good. but my knowledge in Algebra is n't  well. can you explain what do u mean in$ B(0,$-$)$. I don't get the sign $-$ in the $B$. @Laci

Comment: @JohnNash It is a common notation to use $-,\bullet,\cdot$ as placeholders in a function to say: it does not matter what goes here, or to say: this is where the input goes. For example, the dash in $B(0,-)$ together with the surrounding text means that the function $x\mapsto B(0,x)$ is a zero function, or that $B(0,x)=0$ for all $x$. Another usage could be in defining a norm, or inner product - one writes $\|\cdot\|$ where the dot in the left hand side represents where the input goes

Comment: What i meant is suppose you have a vectorspace $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose you have a bilinear form $B:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $v\in V$, then you can plug this vector $v$ in $B$ to get a linear map $B_v:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $B_v(w)=B(v,w)$ (you can check that this is indeed linear). I denoted this map $B_v$ by $B(v,-)$. Now if $v$ is the origin, i.e. $v=\underline{0}\in V$, then $B_{\underline{0}}(w)=B(\underline{0},w)=0$, i.e. $B_{\underline{0}}$ is just the constant $0$ linear function. (Also in my amswer I denoted the zero element of $V$ by $0$.)

Comment: FShrike’s answer is even better. :D